# Stripping output from delimiters and placing all on new line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have data that looks like this (naturally I have GBs of it)

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

and it is all output on one file as such.

I was wondering if it would be possible using regular expressions, `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, or pure bash to pipe the output so I get it to appear as such

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
5,6,7
8,9,10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
echo '[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]' | sed 's/\],\[/\n/g;s/\[\|\]//g'
```

This consists of the two commands

```
s/\],\[/\n/g   # replace all instances of ],[ with newlines
s/\[\|\]//g    # remove remaining [ and ] (at the beginning and end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk

```
echo "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]"|awk  -v OFS="\n" '{gsub(/(\],\[|\]\]|\[\[)/," ");for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){print $i}}'
```

results

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
5,6,7
8,9,10
```